# Symmetric matrices and the sign of the eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

> Let $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ symmetric matrices. Prove that:
>
> (a) If $A > 0$, then $AB$ has only real eigenvalues.
>
> (b) If $x^T Ax \leq x^T B x$, then $\operatorname{ind} A \leq \operatorname{ind} B$.

**Notation.** Let $p_+$ number of the strictly positive eigenvalues of $A$ and $p_-$ number of the stricly negative eigenvalues of $A$, we define $\operatorname{ind} A = p_+ - p_-$.

**Attempt.**

(a) Since $A$ is positive, it has a positive square root. Also,
$$AB = = \sqrt{A}(\sqrt{A}^{-1}AB\sqrt{A})\sqrt{A}^{-1} = \sqrt{A}(\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A})\sqrt{A}^{-1},$$
that is, $AB$ and $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}$ are similar. Since $\sqrt{A}$ and $B$ are symmetric,
$$(\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A})^T = \sqrt{A}^T B^T \sqrt{A}^T = \sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}.$$
Since $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}$ is symmetric, it has only real eigenvalues. The result follows by similarity.

---

(b) I did not have a good idea. The only result that I know about the sign of the eigenvalues is the Law of Inertia, but I do not think it applies here. So, I appreciate any hints.

About the item (a), I would like someone could check my attempt.

Comment: You wrote "Let $p_+$ the strictly positive eigenvalues of $A$ and $p_-$ the stricly negative eigenvalues of $A$". What does that mean? Does it mean "Let $p_+$ be the NUMBER OF strictly positive eigenvalues"? Or maybe the SUM OF THE strictly positive eigenvalues? Or something else?

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's "the number of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) $BA$ is symmetric with respect to the scalar product $\langle A\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, so its eigenvalues are real. Therefore, those of $AB$ are real. Alternative proof: $A^{-1/2}(AB)A^{1/2} = A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is symmetric and thus has real eigenvalues. But as it's similar to $AB$, also $AB$ has real eigenvalues.

(b) By the [minmax-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem), $A$ has at least as many negative eigenvalues as $B$.

Comment: I tried to verify your hint, but I could not understand everything. I can show that $a_1 \leq \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x} \leq a_n$ as $b_1 \leq \frac{x^T B x}{x^T x} \leq b_n$. Taking unit vectors $a_1 \leq x^T A x \leq a_n$ and $b_1 \leq x^T B x \leq b_n$ (here $a_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $b_i$ the eigenvalues of $B$). But I cannot see how to use the minmax theorem to get your claim. I appreciate if you can clarify to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Greg From the condition and the min-max theorem, we get immediately $a_j\le b_j$.